# How can i resolve error 404 of Jersey web service?

Tags: java, web-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJbZ5.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
</head>

<body>
<h1>Object not found!</h1>
<p>


    The requested URL was not found on this server.

  

    If you entered the URL manually please check your
    spelling and try again.



<h2>Error 404</h2>
<address>
  <a href="/">localhost</a><br />
  
  <span>Mon Jan 28 16:43:56 2019<br />
  Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE)</span>
</address>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm developing an application with web services, when I call this service it gives me an error

```
http://localhost:80/clayapi/restservices/getCustomers
```

I am returned this html page

```
 The requested URL was not found on this server.

If you entered the URL manually please check your
spelling and try again.
```

all the other services works well but this doesn't work

The url is correct

```
@Path("getCustomers")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getCustomers(@HeaderParam("token") String token)
{
    if(token.equalsIgnoreCase(this.token)) {
    String sql="select......";
    Database db = new Database();
    String json =  db.executeQueryTOJSON(sql);
    return json;
}else
    return "{\"error\":\"bad token provided\"}; }
```

Comment: Could you please share your code ?

Comment: yes i update now

Comment: What is your context path for your application?

Comment: Change please @Path("getCustomers") to @Path("/getCustomers")
you should have something like this :
http://localhost:80/yourContextPath/getCustomers

Comment: @Path("restservices") 
public class Vtiger_Services { }

Comment: My context path is: http://localhost:80/clayapi/restservices/getCustomers

Comment: You can refer to this tutorial 
https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.3.Final/userguide/html/Using_Path.html

Comment: Actually just add / in @Path annotaiton

Comment: Are you passing @HeaderParam value ?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura in @ Path annotation make same error

Comment: yes i pass the token

Comment: Can you share full working code and code which is not working ?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura i add the image